# Линейное позиционирование блоков

Tags: вёрстка, css

Доброго вечера.

Наткнулся на следующую проблему:
Есть четыре блока с display:inline. Проблема в том, что не получается задать конкретные атрибуты высоты и ширины данным блокам. Они просто их игнорируют. А расширяются только по введенному в них тексту. Собственно как можно сие решить?

Класс блоков:

```
.step {
    background: #ECF2F4;
    color: #333333;
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 20px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Дивами не осилил задачу - пришлось делать старыми добрыми таблицами.

Comment: Дивами легче просто в CSS дать каждому из них float:left;

Comment: А почему бы не использовать для этого ul, li ?

Comment: Давайте вы выложите участок кода с этими блоками и CSS, а мы подправим и объясним, почему не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float: left плох тем, что блоки при этом улетают влево и отцентрировать эту конструкцию весьма сложно.

Есть два хака:

```
1) display: inline-block; /*Глючит в ИЕ*/
2) display: table-cell; /*Вот это нормуль, но уж очень близко к таблице*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Инлайновые элементы так и обрабатываются. Разумнее всего использовать блочные элементы, прописав для них обтекание (float).

Для инлайновых можно попробовать использовать line-height, но только если текст там не более, чем одна строка. Для изменения ширины надо использовать padding-left и padding-right, которые в сумме с размером текста и составят ширину элемента.

Comment: Паддингами менять ширину элементов - плохо! Не учите человека дурному :)

Comment: Во многих случаях это оправданно. Например, если есть горизонтальное навигационное меню - логичнее там использовать именно padding, так как это будет учитывать длину текста.

Comment: С меню соглашусь, но таких оправданных случаев - единицы.

Answer (score 0):

```
.product-row 
  margin: 0 -20px 0px 0;

.product-item 
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 20px 0 0;
```